# Severity mapping between JSF 2.0 and JSR 303 validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bean-validation

I would like to know how to set the severity level by using JSR 303 and show that severity level in a JSF 2.0 application. For now, I only got the message twice.

Backing bean:

```
@NotNull()
@Min(value = 0)
@Max(value = 1000000)
private int kilometres;
```

However, in a input text message

```
<p:messages id="kilometresMessages" showDetail="true" closable="true" />
```

The message is:

```
Minimum value: 0Minimum value: 0
```

I would like to have: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO: Minimum value: 0

So how do I map the FacesMessage.SEVERITY_XXXX to something in my JSR303 annotations?

Can you please help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

In the JSR303 annotations exists a payload property you can use.

```
public final class Severity {

    public static class Error implements Payload {
    }

    public static class Warning implements Payload {
    }

    public static class Info implements Payload {
    }

    private Severity() {

    }
}
```

Then you can define your JSR303 annlotations like

```
@NotNull()
@Min.List({
    @Min(value = 0, payload={Severity.Info.class}),
    @Min(value = -20, payload={Severity.Error.class})
})
@Max(value = 1000000)
private int kilometres;
```

After the validation the corresponding ConstraintViolation object contains the payload.

```
Set<Class<? extends Payload>> payload = ConstraintViolation.getConstraintDescriptor().getPayload();
```

Afterwards you have to translate the constraintViolations into the corresponding messages you want to display. As I'm not a JSF expert, I have to skip this part of the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, JSF already has it's own set of severity object, and it ignores the payload attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The sad truth is that JSR303 / JSR349 (Bean Validation API) messages are always error messages in JSF 2.0-2.2. The severity is a constant - see line 214 of [javax.faces.validator.MessageFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/validator/MessageFactory.java#MessageFactory.getMessage%28java.util.Locale%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

Comment: It is JSR 303 (thus not JSF303). It is JSR 349, since Bean Validation 1.1.

Comment: @Tiny Thanks, I fixed my typo and added the JSF349 bit.